# What is the best way to connect to the Raspberry Pi Zero?

Tags: pi-zero, accessibility

I have got this new raspberry pi zero and I am trying to figure out the best way to access it. It would really help if there is a way to do this without the need of a miniHDMI cable. I would prefer to be able to access it with something like SSH but I do not know how to set that up without already being able to access it. I hope you see the dilema. Please help me. I already have a raspbian image installed on a sd card, I just cant figure out for the life of me how to access the Raspberry Pi while it is on.

Any info on how to do this is greatly appreciated! 
(Also this is not the version with wifi or bluetooth)

Comment: Use serial. https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/USB-To-TTL-FT232RL-FTDI-Serial-Adapter-Converter-Module-For-Arduino-3-3V-5V-Mini/222727769676 running at 3.3V connected to the TX/RX pins https://pinout.xyz/pinout/uart

Comment: Pi Zero doesn't even have microHDMI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frankly if you want to access a Pi remotely you bought the wrong device. It costs more to add networking to a Pi Zero than to get a Pi ZeroW.

There are a couple of options:-

1. Use serial, as suggested by Dougie assuming you have a 3.3V serial interface or dongle on your computer.
2. Use `ssh` over USB. I have never done this, but you need to enable **USB OTG** which requires `dtoverlay=dwc2` in the config.sys.
   if you search you will find a few tutorials e.g. https://desertbot.io/blog/ssh-into-pi-zero-over-usb